# Codeigniter route pattern with prefix

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm working on Codeigniter 3 route mechanism, my application is multi branch, I tried google mail url pattern like `app.com/p/branch_id/controller/method/param1/param2/etc` but some cases it doesn't need prefix `p/branch_id/` for admin or global setting. I think my rule isn't effective.

```
$route['p/(:num)/(:any)'] = '$2';
$route['p/(:num)/(:any)/(:any)'] = '$2/$3';
$route['p/(:num)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = '$2/$3/$4';
$route['p/(:num)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = '$2/$3/$4/$5';

I want achieve
/p/1/booking -> route to controller booking
/p/1/booking/create -> route to controller booking action create()
/p/1/booking/view/1 -> route to controller booking action view($id)

also same thing when user visit
/booking -> route to controller booking
/booking/create -> route to controller booking action create()
/booking/view/1 -> route to controller booking action view($id)
```

How i write the rule for number unknown possible of parameters, when `$route['p/(:num)/(:any)'] = '$2';` just routing index controller only.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it will work.

```
$route['p/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'booking/action/$1/$2';
$route['p/(:num)/(:any)/create'] = 'booking/create/$1/$2';
$route['p/(:num)/(:any)/view/(:num)'] = 'booking/view/$1/$2/$3'; //$3 is record no.
```

> Addition

Or if you want to make action as dynamic variable.

```
$route['p/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'booking/defaultAction/$1/$2';
$route['p/(:num)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'booking/defaultAction/$1/$2'; // here in default action you need to add condition that if its create then execute create functionality. or if its view then execute view funcitonality
```

Comment: But i have to specify all possibility of method in controllers, I have `/booking/validate/` or `/booking/ajax_get_bla_bla, etc...`, I want CI just recognize prefix of the URL, after prefix, just treat like usuals..

Comment: Well, in that case, you can make `(:any)` = action variable after booking token and in basecontroller constructor need to check whats in that variable if its create then execute create function or if its view then check one more paramter as record Id and so on.

Comment: so I can't accomplish this problem with URL route pattern only?, I must override base controller of CI?